# VB.net: Creating one of several derived class objects in response to User

Tags: vb.net, polymorphism

This seems like it should be a really easy question to answer, but I can't seem to find any obvious way to do it.

I have a base class for an object, and it has several derived classes, here ClassA and Class B. I want to take input from the user and create an object of a type determined by their response.

But I can't just put a Dim statement inside a Select Case because the block scope will kill the object immediately.

What I want is something like

`Select Case Input
Case 1
    Dim OutputObject as New ClassA()
Case 2
    Dim OutputObject as New ClassB()
End Select`

I keep feeling there is some obvious way to do this, after all it seems fairly important to the whole idea of polymorphism, but I can't seem to think of it.

Comment: Return an object of your base class, and set it to the construction of class A or class B respectively.

Comment: Take a look at the `WebRequest.Create` method for an example of just what you're trying to do.  It's return type is `WebRequest` but the actual object returned is a derived type based on the protocol of the URL passed in.  It's up to the caller to cast that result as the appropriate type.

Comment: Depending on the details of what you're doing, it might make more sense to use an `Interface` for the return instead of a base class.

Comment: I'll certainly look into the idea of an interface - I'd never actually heard of them before and they are potentially very useful to me. Since VB.net doesn't support multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a [Factory Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). It would look more like this

```
Dim OutputObject as BaseClass

Select Case Input
Case 1
    OutputObject = New ClassA()
Case 2
    OutputObject = New ClassB()
End Select
```

Where you would return the base class.

Comment: I originally had my BaseClass as MustInherit but I removed that and this works perfectly! Although I had to add a lot more protective code to prevent inadvertent use of the base class. Thanks

Comment: @EdmundIreland that's could be a reason to use Interface. The BaseClass to implement an interfave and this factory method would return the interface.